# Android edittext cursor error after settext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

App adds color to text, that gets from `EditText`, adds color and using next code puts text with color back in edittext:

```java
edittext.setText(spannableStringBuilder, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

But after this, the cursor always resets to position 0.  If I don't add any text programmatically, it works fine.  So, how can I set my cursor position to fit the last char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
edittext.setSelection(editText.getText.length())
```

Comment: Aha I saw where I made mistake, I updated selection in part of the code that doesn't execute.